# What are the equivalents of "gksu nautilus" in other Ubuntu Derivatives

Tags: administration, gksu

How do I open the file manager in superuser mode in the same way as doing gksu nautilus in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

## Xubuntu

For your case you have the **Thunar** file manager in which case you would use:

`gksu thunar` or `gksudo thunar`

## Kubuntu

If you had Kubuntu then the File manager would be **Dolphin** in which case you would use:

`kdesu dolphin` or `kdesudo dolphin`

## Ubuntu / Mythbuntu / Edubuntu

If you had Ubuntu you would use **Nautilus** as the File Manager and then would use:

`gksu nautilus` or `gksudo nautilus`.

## Lubuntu

If you had Lubuntu you would use **PCManFM** as the File Manager and then would use:

`gksu pcmanfm` or `gksudo pcmanfm`.

Comment: `kdesu` doesn't seem to exist on Kubuntu Precise; you have to use `kdesudo`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail - Thanks for the update buddy. Have not yet on latest version but on older ones it did exist.

Answer (score 6):

The default file manager in xubuntu is **Thunar.**

> gksu thunar